# How do I get a list of suppressed code analysis warnings from a visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, fxcop

I have enabled code analysis for all the projects in a solution. To overcome various code analysis warnings the code contains numerous code suppression attributes (System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage). I want to get a list of these suppression attributes. I want this list so that I can see if the suppression is still needed and check that we have suitable justifications specified.

Does anyone have or know of a good method/plugin/tool to get a list/report of suppressed code analysis warnings from a visual studio project/solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files`, or default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Just tell it to search for `SuppressMessage` in the entire solution.  It will drop all of the results with their file locations into a dialog, which you can copy/paste into your viewer/editor of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Search or reflection are a couple of obvious brute-force approaches.  You can also get Code Analysis to dump these to its report, including the justification texts.  This can be done either by running `fxcopcmd.exe` with a `/saveMessagesToReport:Active,Excluded` command line option (which can also be set in your Visual Studio project via the `CodeAnalysisSaveMessagesToReport` property if you want to do this routinely).